# teradata get varchar representation of a float value

Tags: casting, teradata

I am trying to select float values as varchar strings (for flat file export).
Have found several useful examples but none that seem to exactly match.

We have many different values in the data, that should all show up correctly and remain exactly how it was

e.g.,

23.30  should not become 23.3
23.0   should not become 23. or 23
23     should not become 23. or 23.0
23.33  should not become in 23.3300

many thanks for the help&time.

Comment: It's impossible, a Float doesn't store any info about the number of fractional digits. Why do you think you need this and how do you load those valies?

Comment: we basically do not want to influence the precision... but your reply makes me wonder if I need to have another look at the requirement, thanks for that info. They want us to populate an excel....

Answer (score 0):

So after dnoeth'S question i had another thought and I'll just use

select cast(cast(cast(1234567890.19 as float) as NUMBER) as varchar(200))

Comment: There's no need to cast to a FLOAT first and then to a NUMBER unless you want to loose precision, 38 vs. 15 digits (Of course Excel works with Floats only and will always loose precision). If you already got a FLOAT you can also simply apply the NUMBER format: `To_Char(FloatCol, 'TM9')`. Of course this will trim trailing zeroes, too.

Comment: thanks, the innermost cast was just to make sure I have a float, meaning for test reasons :)